# Why is $\int_{[x,y]}| f |\leq |x-y| \int_{R}| f| $?

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Hi in the proof of f integrable, $g(x)= \int_{[0,x]} f dt$ is uniformly continuous, i saw a proof that uses the following argument. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, take $δ := \epsilon^-1 · (\int |f|dt) >0$ since f is integrable. Let $x<y $such that $|x − y| < δ$, Then,$|g(x) − g(y)| ≤ \int_{[x,y]} |f(t)|dt ≤ |x − y|\int_{R}
|f(t)|dt < \epsilon. $

My question is, how do we get that $\int_{[x,y]} |f(t)|dt ≤ |x − y|\int_{R}
|f(t)|dt$? I have tried to bound it and only able to conclude that $\int_{[x,y]} |f(t)|dt\leq |x − y| sup(|f|)$ ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The proposed inequality is false. That would imply that $g$ is Lipschitz on $\Bbb{R}$, which then implies that $f$ is bounded. Of course, there are integrable functions which are unbounded on any open sets. This necessitates the control over such exceptional 'peaks'.

Comment: I see, so if f is bounded and integrable, then we can do this?

Comment: @Socchi: No, even then it is false.  Take $f = 2 \cdot 1_{[0,1/2]}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the proposed proof is wrong.  A simple counterexample is $f(x) = |x|^{-1/2}$ for $-1 \le x \le 1$, $f(x)=0$ otherwise.  Note $g(x) = 2 \sqrt{|x|}$ for $-1 \le x \le 1$ which is not Lipschitz.

Comment: But your f(x) is not integrable?

Comment: I was worried about the region, thanks. I wonder whether a part of the proof is missing?

Comment: Oh, at infinity, you're right.  Fixed.  What's relevant is what happens near 0.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that claim is wrong? Maybe some part of the proof is missing to get to that conclusion?

Comment: I think it's just wrong.  I can't think of any useful class of functions $f$ for which it is true.